# Join two tables and display it in a table

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

I have two tables "rps_users" contains columns named as id,membership_no, volunteer_name and email , and "rps_volunteer_score" contains volunteer_id,registration_assessor,interviewer,professional_registration_advisor and registration_category.Here the id and volunteer_id are same.The volunteers present in the "rps_users" table have multiple records in "rps_volunteer_score" table under different "registration_category".
I want to display a  table contains membership No,volunteer name,email and Type. The "Type" records finds on the basis of "rps_volunteer_score" records.ie,

```
if( $interviewer!="" && $interviewer <= 4 )echo "Interviewer";
if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor >= 2 && $registration_assessor <= 4 )echo "Assessor";
if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor >= 3 && $registration_assessor <= 4)echo "Moderator";
if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor = '4' ) echo "Registrar";
if($professional_registration_advisor !="" && $professional_registration_advisor= '1')echo "PRA";
```

I used this to join two tables

```
public function get_volunteers_list($condition)
{

    $this->db->select("u.id,u.membership_number,u.family_name,u.first_name,u.email_address, vs.registration_assessor, vs.interviewer,vs.professional_registration_advisor");
    $this->db->from(self::$tbl_name . " as u");
    $this->db->join(Volunteer_score::$tbl_name . " as vs", "u.id = vs.volunteer_id","left");
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    //var_dump($this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result();
}
```

But I got multiple records of one volunteer.
Please help me to find a solution.
This is the controller code.

```
    $volunteer_list = $this->Users->get_volunteers_list(array("u.staff"=>'N'));
    var_dump($volunteer_list);
    $this->data["volunteer_list"] = $volunteer_list;
```

Comment: i have one doubt, if there are multiple record in second table, which `interviewer` value will you consider, or you shud sum the value??

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju I want to consider all the values under different registration category.CEng,IEng,EngTech,Fellow and ICTTech these are the different category.Each category contains $interviewer,$registration_assessor and $professional_registration_advisor value.

Comment: Now my o/pis the above screen shot.here multiplication in records.I want to change it

Comment: previous comment was a bit confusing. for second row u have 4 values, in that you want only one rite??

Comment: I want only one row in same membership No.In screen shot display more than one record of same membership No.This is because of multiple records in 2nd table under same Membership No(only their registration_category is different)

Comment: ok... can 1 user have more tan 1 membership_number??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91706/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-ann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should group by `membership number`

add this line before `get()`

```
$this->db->group_by("u.membership_number");
```